# Замена текстовых смайлов графическими

Tags: php, javascript

Пользователь вводит сообщение, оно ajax-ом отправляется в php и там нужно определить есть ли в нем текстовые смайлы.

```
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$smail = array(":)", ":(");
$grafic = array("<img src = '../image/Smile.png' alt='Smile' align='middle'>",
"<img src = '../image/Sad.png' alt='Smile' align='middle'>");
$new_message = str_replace($smile, $grafic, $message);
```

Далее `$new_message` помещается в массив, кодируется в json, записывается и отправляется обратно в ajax если все успешно, a он в свою очередь показывает сообщение.

```
$content = array("time" => $time, "user" => $user, "message"  => $new_message);

file_put_contents($file, json_encode($content, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),FILE_APPEND);

echo json_encode($content);
```

Вот вывод на экран сообщений.

```
success: function(arr) {
            arr = $.parseJSON(arr)
            $('#messages').append($('.mess_hide').clone().addClass('mess_tmp').removeClass('mess_hide'));
            $('.mess_tmp>.time').html(arr.time);
            $('.mess_tmp>.name').html(arr.user);
            $('.mess_tmp>.message').html(arr.message);
            $('.mess_tmp').removeClass('mess_tmp');
        }
```

А это html

```
<table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
        <td class="time"></td>
        <td class="name"></td>
        <td class="message"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Но не работает, что может быть не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых: у вас опечатка в `$smail = array(":)", ":(");` заменить надо на $smile.
Во-вторых: как то сложно получается, аяксом отправляется запрос. Думаю стоит просто использовать библиотеку, например, [CSS Emoticons](https://os.alfajango.com/css-emoticons/).

Вам всеголишь нужно подключить её:

```html
<link href="stylesheets/jquery.cssemoticons.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="javascripts/jquery.cssemoticons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

и на классе где есть смайлик вызвать  `$('.comment').emoticonize();`

Comment: Cпасибо, ваш ответ помог)